# merge python dictionaries when a key has a certain value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of python dictionaries, looking like this:

```
[{key1: value1, key2: array1}, {key1: value2, key2: array2}, {key1: value3, key3: array3},...]
```

In my case, some of these dictionaries have the same value for key1, for example, value1 = value3. How can I end up getting an array of dictionaries that will look like this?

```
 [{key1: value1, key2: array1+array3}, {key1: value2, key2: array2},...]
```

where "array1+array3" is a single array with appended elements of the original array1 and array3 arrays?

edit: this is not merging by key; each dictionary in the array has strictly the same structure: {key1: "some_string", key2: [an array]} - my problem is that I wish to "merge" them on the "some_string", so the [an array], the value of key2, will be concatenated with arrays from other dictionaries in the list that have the same "some_string" as value of key1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do what you want is to re-structure your data, at least temporarily. If you were to use a dictionary that mapped from `value` to `array` (without the fixed keys), you could put all the data into a single place and efficiently detect when duplicate values occur so that you can merge the values together. If need be, you can turn the single dictionary back into a list of smaller dictionaries afterwards.

Try something like this:

```
merged = {}
for d in list_of_dicts:
    if d["key1"] not in merged:
        merged[d["key1"]] = d["key2"]
    else:
        merged[d["key1"]] += d["key2"]

# if necessary, put back into a list of dicts:
merged_list = [{"key1": k, "key2": v} for k, v in merged.items()]
```

The order of the list at the end will be arbitrary. If you want to preserve the order of the dicts in the original list, you could use an `OrderedDict` for `merged`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to group by `key1`, you can use `itertools.groupby()`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

list_of_dicts = [{'key1': 1, 'key2': [1, 2]},
                 {'key1': 2, 'key2': [3, 4]},
                 {'key1': 1, 'key2': [5, 6]}]

grouped = groupby(sorted(list_of_dicts, key=itemgetter('key1')),
                  key=itemgetter('key1'))
result = [{'key1': k,
           'key2': [elt for item in g for elt in item['key2']]}
          for k, g in grouped]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'key2': [1, 2, 5, 6], 'key1': 1}, {'key2': [3, 4], 'key1': 2}]
```